# Is it illegal to carry a foam baseball bat as a prop on Halloween in the UK?

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom, is-x-legal, weapons

I am thinking of doing a 'Jacket' from *Hotline Miami* cosplay/dress up perhaps for Halloween or a convention. I am trying to think about props, but I am worried about the laws against having anything appearing realistic and potentially getting into any trouble or harm. I would not be holding a fake gun, I am aware of that law, and also did some research on real baseball bats and the legality of being in possession of one.

Would a **foam** baseball bat [like this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B06XTVD3TJ/ref=ox_sc_act_image_1?smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&psc=1) used as a prop still be okay to carry?

If I read on their company's site correctly, it is lightweight, and the plastic rod is inside in the middle and the foam surrounds it to make the look of the bat and there is a wood print on it. I was going to apply a couple bandages and potentially use a bit of brushed on fake blood to complete the look, but I am uncertain if I can get in trouble out on Halloween night for this even though it isn't real. I would also be wearing a rooster mask over my head.

I do not intend to cause distress to the public at all, and it would simply be used as a prop. I will most likely be with a couple uni friends going straight to another friend's party a few streets away if it was for Halloween. For a convention such as MCM Comic Con, however, I will search the rules and ask them about this also if necessary.

Comment: In my teens I used to play cricket for a local club, our coach was a policeman as his day job and never mentioned anything to us about us carrying our own bats to and from practice. I imagine any police who spot you wandering around by clubs with it will be keeping an eye on you but I don't think it is actually illegal. This is all anecdotal though so I'm leaving this as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

It is almost certainly fine as long has you have a "good reason".

[The police website](https://www.police.uk/crime-prevention-advice/possession-of-weapons/) give a list of examples when carrying a knife would have a "good reason" (like a chef getting a set of knives out of her car, for example). Likewise, a plastic knife isn't considered a weapon as long as you don't start threatening people with it.

As long as you don't start swinging it around, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is in most places illegal (a crime) to put someone in fear of their life or in fear of suffering bad injuries. If this plastic baseball bat looks like a real one, and you threaten to hit someone with it in a way that puts them into reasonable fear for their life or health, you may be guilty of assault, and you may suffer if you get hurt by someone acting in self defense. You may also suffer if someone calls the police, and they feel threatened by you, and they carry guns.

I don't know exactly what would put someone in reasonable fear, and neither do you, so it would be wiser to not carry it.